# Is IBM Webshpere MQ 6 compatible with JBoss EAP 6.2?

Tags: ibm-mq, jboss-eap-6

I was trying to deploy a component on JBoss EAP 6.2 serever.My application listens to IBM Websphere MQ 6.I would like to know if MQ 6 is compatible with JBoss 6.2

Answer (score 0):

There aren't any known issues with using IBM MQ 6 with JBoss EAP 6.2.  Neither Red Hat nor IBM officially test and support this configuration, however.